# MP4 container writer in Java

Tags: java, mp4, h.264

I would like to find a FREE MP4 (container) writer for Java. I do not need an encoder, only something which can write the correct atoms given their expected values. **Bonus** for such a library that also can write "valid" F4V.

I would prefer a pure Java solution rather than something using JNI or external executables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though my answer comes very late you could have a look into my MP4 Parser/Unparser at [Github](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser). You can parse MP4 files, modify them and write the result. You can even start from scratch creating boxes programatically and write your object representation to some sink.

Comment: On the outside this looks pretty promising, once I check it out you may get the "check"

Comment: Currently we're writing h264 into flv format and its working for us; A full mp4 writer probably wont make the 1.0 release with so much left to do.

Comment: Is it possible to render a video (mp4) using series of bitmap images.
i am doing it in android but stuck at this point. can you give me a reference? I want a pure java solution. Thanks and regards

Comment: I've released my first rev of Red5 using mp4parser (reading) and liking it so far

Comment: @SebastianAnnies Can we write the object  representation to Android media Player directly so android media player will be acting like a sink. Is that even possible ? So it will be like all done in Memory rather than writing to a file as the sink and then supplying the file URL to the android media player.

Comment: Please ask a question on Stackoverflow. It doesnt make to much  sense to me to have this discussion in the comments @ROCKY

Comment: @SebastianAnnies I did add a separate question and it's here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886365/mp4parser-can-we-have-android-mediaplayer-directly-act-as-a-sink

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at JCodec ( http://jcodec.org ). It contains an MP4 library and MP4 demuxer and muxer.

Answer (score 2):

May be you are looking for something like [StreamBaby](http://streambaby.googlecode.com/).

Comment: I see they have code for a splitter and interleave writer in java, but they are using FFMpeg. The writer does not look complete but its a start.

Comment: Also, FFmpeg is not an option for us

Answer (score 1):

Can't vouch for it, but [red5](http://code.google.com/p/red5/) is an open source flash server written in Java, which claims support for streaming mp4 and has [implementations of mp4](http://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/java/server/branches/paulg_mp4/src/org/red5/io/?r=3537#io/mp4) IO objects which may be able to create said format.

Also, IBM created their [Toolkit For MPEG-4](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/tk4mpeg4) a while back and though it's not free, it might help.

Comment: Funny that you mention Red5, I'm a core dev on the project :). And yes, I know about IBM's implementation but it, as you verify is not FREE.

Comment: Hah! After seeing the mp4 impl classes in red5 I was considering using it for an old abandoned project. Can it not create mp4 output, or are you simply looking for anothere implementation to compare to?

Comment: The mp4 code in red5 is just a reader, but the server is perfectly capable of streaming live or recorded mp4 content. It just can't write it to disk.

Comment: Correction, it can write it to disk but only in an FLV container

Answer (score 1):

FFMPEG's java bindings?
http://fobs.sourceforge.net/f4jmf_first.html

Or simpler a JNA proxy over some C++ MP4 library.

Comment: I need a solution that does not use JNI or JNA bindings, it cannot rely upon "native" code.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a [QuickTimeWriter](http://www.randelshofer.ch/blog/2010/10/writing-quicktime-movies-in-pure-java/) class which can write a QuickTime container in pure Java.

As far as I know, the QuickTime file format is structurally equivalent to MPEG-4 Part 14. There are only a few minor differences in the fields inside atoms/boxes.

So, with an MPEG-4 spec on your lap, and a few hours of work, you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

The Java I've seen which modifies MP4 files would invoke [Nero AAC Codec](http://www.nero.com/enu/technologies-aac-codec.html) externally (a Windows native .exe which Nero does not supply the source for) to modify AAC files (which are Apple's audio-only MP4 files). It works for audio only, not to video.