# add timestamps to an mp4 container

Tags: timestamp, h.264, mp4

Suppose I receive packets of H264 video, each with a timestamp. Is there a way to store these timestamps in an mp4 container? Or another container type?

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Writing an mp4 multiplexer from scratch or using a library?

Comment: the video data is coming in via RTP packets, and I would like to write it to an mp4 using DirectShow.

Comment: I would add the directshow tag to this question. The answer is yes. In fact, the player has to know when each frame should be presented. ...or rather, for how long each frame should be displayed. This works the same way wether it's constant or variable fps in mp4. I don't know much about directshow so wouldn't be able to tell you how it works.

Answer (score 0):

In `MP4` container, for every sample count, there is a corresponding timestamp stored as part of `stts` box. For a given sample, you would require `stco` for chunk offset, `stsc` for sample to chunk, `stsz` for size of the sample, `stss` for key frame indication and `stts` for decoding.

Comment: is there an API for doing all these things?

Comment: @user1896048 There are some free public domain mp4 writers available.You could refer to this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663797/mp4-container-writer-in-java